# Probability - binomial coefficient or...

Tags: probability

the question I'm having trouble answering is this. There is a treasure chest that contains 40 gold coins, 10 silver, and 30 bronze. There is a small slit in the top of the treasure chest. You turn the chest upside down and shake it about. What is the probability that the first coin to come out is gold, followed by bronze?

My solution was to use binomial coefficient; (40 choose 1) * (30 choose 1) / (80 choose 2) = 0.38

Two of my classmates' solutions were: (40/80) * (30/79) = 0.19

They both make sense, but produce different answers. Which is correct and why?

Answer (score 2):

When you use binomial coefficients (combinations), you are saying the order doesn't matter - but you do want a specific order here! You want gold, then bronze.

Your solution only counts for picking a pair of coins at once, and counting the pairs that have a gold and bronze coin in the hand. That counts twice as many possibilities!

Let's explain your peers' solution. There are 80 coins, 40 of which are gold. Now suppose you pick a gold coin first. That leaves 79 coins, 30 of which are bronze. By the Fundamental Counting Principle (multiplication principle),

$$ P( \text{gold, then bronze} ) = \frac{40}{80} \cdot \frac{30}{79} = \frac{15}{79}$$

which is half of your solution.

The punchline - check if order matters!